# How to target value of input field that has an id that is composed using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

On button click I want to get the value of the input field. However, I am having trouble targeting the input field because the field id is another composed value.

I have tried `this.value` which appears to only pass me the req.id and not the value entered in the input field.
I understand that the proper way to get an input field value is: 
`$(selector).val()`

However, the following does not work with the current implementation.
`$(incidentNumber+${req.id}).val()`

```
<tr th:each="req : ${requests}">       
 <td><input th:id="incidentNumber+${req.id}" th:name="incidentNumber+${req.id}"
                       style="width:100%" type="text" th:value="${req.incidentNumber}">
<button th:value="${req.id}"class="button" type="button" onclick="validate_ticket_number(this.value)">Update</button></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I expect the output to be the entered value in the "incidentNumber+${req.id}" input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to concatenate string is:

```
th:id="'incidentNumber'+${req.id}"
```

When you access it in Javascript (`jQuery` selector by Id of the element) you can't use the `thyemeleaf` expression, it has to be:

```
$('#incidentNumber100').val() // req id 100 is just an example
```

If you want to make it dynamic, pass the Id of the element to the target function and in the function retrieve the value using the Id.

```
<button th:value="${req.id}"class="button" type="button"
th:onclick="'validate_ticket_number(\'incidentNumber'+${req.id}+'\')'"> Update</button>
```

And then in the `validate_ticket_number()` function access the value using the supplied id like:

```
function validate_ticket_number(id){
  var value = $(id).val();
}
```

Comment: To clarify: with the current code implementation, is not possible then to target the specific input field dynamically (I need to know the req.id in advance)?

Comment: To make it dynamic, you should pass the Id to the method instead of value like `onclick="'validate_ticket_number(\'incidentNumber'+${req.id}+'\'')"` and then in the `validate_ticket_number()` function access the value using the supplied id like `$(id).val()`

Comment: @frankthetannk I have updated the answer to incorporate your query on making it dynamic. Take a look and let me know if still, your problem persists.

Comment: Is it possible there is a syntax typo in: `"'validate_ticket_number(\'incidentNumber'+${req.id}+'\'')"` everything appears to load properly until I make that change. Then I receive the following error in developer tools in Chrome `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: Yes, it would be `"'validate_ticket_number(\'incidentNumber'+${req.id}+'\')'"`. Modified in the answer as well. To fix this kind of problems see in the browser inspector/view source what's the HTML content generated and fix it as necessary in the source code.

Comment: if you want to use expressions in your on click function, you need to use `th:onclick` instead of `th:click`.  Also, I would recommend this format to improve compatibility with Thymeleaf 3.  Something like this for example: `<button th:value="${req.id}" class="button" type="button" th:data-incidentId="|incidentNumber${req.id}|" onclick="validate_ticket_number(this.getAttribute('data-incidentId');"> Update</button>`

Comment: Agreed with `th:onclick` and the improved format suggestion.

Comment: It looks like there is a missing `)` near the end of the `validate_ticket_number` function. The following works: `<button th:value="${req.id}" class="button" type="button" th:data-incidentId="|incidentNumber${req.id}|" onclick="validate_ticket_number(this.getAttribute('data-incidentId'))"> Update</button></a>` however, the value retrieved in the calling function is `incidentNumber9` when it should be the entered value in the input field.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you are passing the Id of the field to `validate_ticket_number(id)` function and in that function, you can do `$("#"+id).val()` to get the input field value.

Comment: You are absolutely right @fiveelements that has resolved my issue! Thank you. To clarify the specific code was `<button th:value="${req.id}" class="button" type="button" th:data-incidentId="|incidentNumber${req.id}|" onclick="validate_ticket_number(this.getAttribute('data-incidentId'))"> Update</button></a>` in combination with: `$("#"+id).val()` within the `validate_ticket_number()` function

Comment: @frankthetannk glad to know that your problem is resolved.